# Can anyone suggest a place to start with javascript touch events for the web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mobile, touch

I would like to learn how to make image galleries and content sliders that can support both touch and mouse events. What's a good place to start learning about touch events?

I can't seem to find any official documentation.

Are there helpful touch libraries supported through jQuery that normalize the api?

Comment: It's worth looking here to see how well touch events are supported in mobile browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good **Apple documentation** on touch events (but not only):

> [list of supported events on Safari Web Content Guide: Handling Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5)

You can also **visit this page** (JS script created by me) on your touch-enabled device and see what events are being triggered:

> http://jsfiddle.net/wzD8A/embedded/result/

I believe **different devices may fire different events**. For example my own tablet-convertible PC does not fire touch events, when I click the screen, and Android may behave differently than eg. iPhone. I do not know any source of comprehensive information about the differences in this matter.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that you don't want to use a mobile framework for some reason.

If you don't want to use a mobile framework, which is highly recommended, you can go straight to the native API, of course. But be aware that you might find vendor specific differences that are already handled by the mobile frameworks and might be hard to deal with.

Here's a fairly good tutorial on how to do touch and mobile optimizations based solely on native APIs:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html

Answer (score 1):

There are some JavaScript Touch Libraries such the following:

- [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) (commercial or open source license)
- [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) (free)
- [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) (free)

Comment: These are full fledged frameworks. I am creating sliders and galleries for websites not apps.

Comment: *Sencha Touch* is distributed on multiple licenses, including an open source license. http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/license/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get familiar with jquery mobile touch events, I am sure there is lots of resources on it but here is one that I found useful

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: But doesn't this imply that I use the entire framework just to get a handle on touch events?

Comment: @AmitErandole yeah you'll have to use the entire framework to use the touch events

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply interested in learning about touch events, iTunes has the Apple Developer Conference Videos from the [2010](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) and [2011](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) conferences available for free. It requires registration, but again the registration is free.

I used the information here to create a mobile-friendly version of an application and it worked fine on iOS and Android. (Blackberry didn't have a browser that supported touch events at that time.)

This will give you an overview of how to use touch events and gestures in your web apps. Watch the "Adding Touch and Gesture Detection to Web Pages on iPhone OS" from the 2010 conference as well as the "Hidden Gems for Web Apps" and "Understanding Layout and Gestures in Safari on iOS and Lion" presentations from the 2011 conference.

Hope this helps.